# Modifying an assembly in nuget package throws file not found exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I'm using an MVC application. System.Web.Mvc.dll version 5.0.0.0 is referred through nuget packages.

I have manually replaced this dll in packages folder with System.Web.Mvc version 5.0.0.1 to upgrade my mvc dll. I have done all the changes in my web.config file

Now, running the application throws file not found exception for System.Web.Mvc version 5.0.0.0 but this version is not specified anywhere inside the MVC project.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it ?

**EDIT:**

1) Project compiled successfully 
2) Runnung this projrect throws this exceptio

So, I think when running the mvc application the nuget package is trying to restore the old mvc dll version 5.0.0.0

Any suggestions ???

Comment: I think you can update your dll directly through NuGet Manager. Just click on `Updates` menu instead of `nuget.org` in the NuGet Manager window.

Comment: thanks, I'll try your suggestion